# How can I change the disk id of a freshly cloned disk?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, partitioning, ssd, clone

Situation: I cloned a Windows 10 system SSD (old) onto a bigger externally connected SSD (new) and then replaced the old SSD with the new one. I booted the system and everything worked fine.

Problem: When I now connect the old SSD to the Windows 10 computer (in an external USB enclosure) it is not recognized. It is not brought online and I can not see the old SSD in the explorer.

I assume this is because the old SSD and the new SSD have identical disk ids and Windows 10 ignores drives with disk ids which it already knows (or at least which are identical to the system disk).

Question: How can I change the disk id of the old SSD?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change the disk id of a disk:

- In `cmd.exe` or a Power Shell enter: `diskpart`.
- List all disks using `list disk`.
- Select the disk you want to change (most likely the one which is `offline`): `select disk N`, where `N` is the number of the list printed by `list disk`.
- Type `uniqueid disk` to see the current disk id. It will be identical to the system disk for cloned disks.
- Change the disk id of the old SSD by typing `uniqueid disk id=12345678`. The id might be a 32-bit id (like in this example, for a disk having an MBR) or a 128-bit UUID. Just change the last hex digit to something else.
- `exit`
- Disconnect the drive and reconnect it.
- The disk (its partitions) should now be recognized.